# How do I stretch this SVG path to fit the height of the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, responsive-design

I have the following SVG:

```html
<svg class="svgwave" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 301 301" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" height="100%" width="100%">
    <path id="wavepath" d="M145.5 301.5H13C6.09645 301.5 0.5 295.904 0.5 289V13C0.5 6.09645 6.09644 0.5 13 0.5H289C295.904 0.5 301.5 6.09644 301.5 13V289C301.5 295.904 295.904 301.5 289 301.5H156.5 H13C6.09645 301.5 0.5 295.904 0.5 289V13C0.5 6.09645 6.09644 0.5 13 0.5H289C295.904 0.5 301.5 6.09644 301.5 13V289C301.5 295.904 295.904 301.5 289 301.5H156.5 H13C6.09645 301.5 0.5 295.904 0.5 289V13C0.5 6.09645 6.09644 0.5 13 0.5H289C295.904 0.5 301.5 6.09644 301.5 13V289C301.5 295.904 295.904 301.5 289 301.5H156.5 H13C6.09645 301.5 0.5 295.904 0.5 289V13C0.5 6.09645 6.09644 0.5 13 0.5H289C295.904 0.5 301.5 6.09644 301.5 13V289C301.5 295.904 295.904 301.5 289 301.5H156.5" style="fill: transparent; stroke: transparent; stroke-width: 1px;" width="100%" height="100%"></path>
                        <text text-anchor="left">
                            <textPath style=" fill-opacity: 1" href="#wavepath" side="left" startOffset="0%" textLength="1175">
                            <animate attributeName="startOffset" from="20%" to="42%" begin="0s" dur="12s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                            Some text Some textSome textSome text  Some text Some text Some text Some text                      </textPath>
                        </text>
                    </svg>
```

What this does is move text around a `path`

The problem is that the `path` already has set dimensions, so I cannot stretch the height of it vertically.

I am able to change the width, but the height always remains in such a way that the element is in a **square** shape.

How can I make the height responsive, not just the width. Even if I change the `viewbox` attribute, it will always be in a square shape (determined by the `path`) element.

I have tried doing the following *hack*, where I replace the vertical-based values with a variable of the document height but it gives weird results:

```
    theY = $(window).outerHeight();
    newP = `M 145.5 ${theY} H 13 C 6.0964 ${theY} 0.8 591.808 0.5 578 V 26 C 0.5 12.1928 6.0964 1 13 1 H 289 C 295.904 1 301.5 12.1928 301.5 26 V 578 C 301.5 591.808 295.904 ${theY} 289 ${theY} H 156.5 H 13 C 6.0964 ${theY} 0.5 591.808 0.5 578 V 26 C 0.5 12.1928 6.0964 1 13 1 H 289 C 295.904 1 301.5 12.1928 301.5 26 V 578 C 301.5 591.808 295.904 ${theY} 289 ${theY} H 156.5 H 13 C 6.0964 ${theY} 0.5 591.808 0.5 578 V 26 C 0.5 12.1928 6.0964 1 13 1 H 289 C 295.904 1 301.5 12.1928 301.5 26 V 578 C 301.5 591.808 295.904 ${theY} 289 ${theY} H 156.5 H 13 C 6.0964 ${theY} 0.5 591.808 0.5 578 V 26 C 0.5 12.1928 6.0964 1 13 1 H 289 C 295.904 1 301.5 12.1928 301.5 26 V 578 C 301.5 591.808 295.904 ${theY} 289 ${theY} H 156.5`;
    $("svg path").attr("d",newP);
```

Comment: set preserveAspectRatio="none" instead of what you have now

Comment: @RobertLongson Works, thank you! Though the text itself gets stretched vertically now (looks weird but the positioning of the text is good though), is there a way to apply `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the Path but not on the Text?

Comment: No there is not. I mean you could use javascript to work out how distorted the window is and scale the text in the opposite way I suppose, but there's nothing built in.